# Why does my hamster bite me during the night?

Tags: behavior, hamsters

My hamster Luigi lives free in my room, his cage is open and he can go in there whenever he wants. I bought him 5 months ago and he never had aggressive behaviors until now. In fact, in the past few  weeks he started to come on my bed during the night and bite me aggressively on the hands and arms, and it actually hurts! I can't really understand his behavior, even because during the day he's always nice and he comes when I call him.
Do you have any idea about why Luigi behaves this way?

P.S I don't really move when I sleep, so there are no possibilities to smash him :)

Answer (score 1):

You say that you don't move at might, but it's possible that you might be, and then waking your hampster when it's sleeping or otherwise close to you.

http://thehamsterhouse.com/hamster-info/hamster-behavior/why-do-hamsters-bite/

> Never disturb your hamster while it’s sleeping; if you do it will be grumpy and scared, and it’s likely to bite. And never approach your hamster from behind, as you are likely to startle it.

Comment: But should he be awake during the night? I mean he goes on his wheel and I hear him digging..

Comment: @AsiaPanizzi Hamsters are nocturnal. They like to sleep during the day, and should be allowed to do so.

Comment: Thanks @Mick :) Yes I am aware of that, I'm never at home during the day so there are no possibilities of disturbing him during his sleeping. My problem is that he comes on my bed and he bites me during the night (when it's my turn for sleeping) and I don't understand why.

Comment: Maybe he wants to play. We kept Syrian hamsters when I was a kid, but they were always locked in their cages when we were asleep.